# Check that the linear operator is bounded not compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the linear operator M : L^2[0,1] to L^2[0,1] defined by (Mf)(x) = xf(x) is bounded but  not compact.

Answer (score 4):

1. $||Mf||_2^2 =\int_0^1x^2f(x)^2 \le \int_0^1f(x)^2=||f||_2^2$. This shows that $M$ is bounded.
2. It is easy to see: $(Mf|g)=(f|Mg)$ for all $f,g \in  L^2[0,1] $ (where $(*|*)$ denotes the inner product on $L^2[0,1] $).

Hence $M$ is symmetric. Now suppose that $M$ is compact. Then $M$ has an eigenvalue !

Its your turn to show that $M$ has no eigenvalues !